# Python RegEx to find a string between < and >

Tags: python, regex

I have a `Python` application where I am trying to parse out information between `<` and `>` in a string.

My string is:

```
##MESSAGE=<A=test_id,B=.,C=type,D="Description">\n
```

I have tried the `Python`:

```
pattern = re.compile('*\<(\w+)\>*')
match = pattern.match(line)
```

but my pattern still does not appear to be correct because `match` always equals `None`.

Can anyone see what the issue is in my pattern?

Comment: `*` is a greedy operator.

Comment: Match can't equal anything, the regex won't compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pattern = re.compile('<(\w+)>')
```

or

```
pattern = re.compile('<([^>]*)>')
```

You can use the patterns like this way:

using `re.search()`

```
x = re.search(pattern, input)
print x.group(1)
```

using `re.match()`: you have to add `.*` at the both ends of the regex. See the example:

```
pattern = re.compile('.*<([^>]*)>.*')
#                     ^^         ^^
x = pattern.match(input)
print x.group(1)
```

Comment: Perfect explanation! I'll accept as soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.search` instead, `re.match` attempts to match from the beginning of the line.